# Symfony 2 FOSFacebookBundle custom redirection before login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i'm using the FOSUserBundle and the FOSFacebookBundle (for version SF 2.0.x) in my project. Additionally, i implemented and custom FacebookProvider as described in the FOSFacebookBundle documentation. I would like to achieve the following workflow:
1.) A user visits my portal the first time
2.) He clicks the Facebook-Login-Button
3.) Now i need to check, if this user, who clicked the Facebook-Login-Button has already Facebook-Friends on my portal. 
4.) If he has friends, redirect him to a sign-up page (including information from Facebook like, username, first_name, last_name, etc.) with prefilled input fields.
5.) If he has no Facebook-friends on my portal, redirect him to another page

I've started looking at the Webprofiler, which events are called. I've started creating my own event listener as descried on this page: http://www.dobervich.com/2011/10/13/login-redirection-revisited/   but the profile shows me my listener in the list of "not called listeners": security.interactive_login   SecurityListener::onSecurityInteractiveLogin

Does anyone know, how i could customize this pre-login-check and redirect a user to a page?

Would be great to get some help on this.

Thank you,
Ramo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure a custom authentication success handler. Configure a service that implements [AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.0/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface.php):

```
facebook_auth_success_handler:
    class: MyHandler
    public: false
    arguments:
        # your dependencies...
```

Then add this handler to `security.yml` under your `fos_facebook` block:

```
firewalls:
    foo:
        fos_facebook:
            success_handler: facebook_auth_success_handler
```

The handler itself should look something like this:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    $user = $token->getUser();
    $hasFriendsHereAlready = // your logic here
    if ($hasFriendsHereAlready) {
        $route = 'foo';
    } else {
        $route = 'bar';
    }
    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate($route));
}
```

Comment: Hey Kris, thank you for this solution. The Problem is just, that with the default FacebookUserProvider a user is created and this user is logged in too... so, i get redirected to my $route , but the problem is, when i enter another pass, that's only accesible for logged in user, i get there too. what i try to achieve is, that this user is just able to visit the landing page and another page. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Okay, found a way to logout the user out with the security.context